# What is wrong with my use of "find -print0"?

Tags: find, filenames

I'm confused by this experiment (in Bash):

```
$ mkdir 'foo\n'
$ find . -print0 | od -c
0000000   .  \0   .   /   f   o   o   \   n  \0
0000012
```

As you can see, "find" is correctly delimiting the output with null characters, but it escapes the newline in the directory name as "foo\n" with a backslash "n". Why is it doing this? I told it "-print0" which says "This allows file names that contain newlines ... to be correctly interpreted by programs that process the find output." The escaping should not be necessary, since "\0" is the delimiter, not "\n".

Comment: You made a directory called literally `foo\n`, with a backslash in its name.

Comment: Soo ... embarrassing .... but learned something from the answers, thank you all.

Comment: If you did an `ls` you would have seen that.

Comment: @Bakuriu, no because `ls` prints exactly what I passed to mkdir, `'foo\n'`...

Comment: There is no Neulinge in your filename, ‚\n‘ is a literal 2 char string

Comment: @Metamorphic That's exactly my point. If there was a real newline it would print `'foo'$'\n'` (at least my `/bin/sh`

Comment: @Bakuriu, your reasoning is circular. You said that `ls` would have helped me. But if I had known that '\n' did not signify a newline, then I would have seen this at the `mkdir` command. `ls` did not show me anything I hadn't already seen. What would you think I learned from running `ls`? I'm not saying I'm not dumb, just maybe a little more awake than you right now :) And why do people keep upvoting this question? It's my worst question!

Comment: @Metamorphic It's in HNQ is why, and it's there because the review queue hasn't gotten around to closing the question yet since it's the weekend. They will probably keep trickling in for a few more hours at least.

Comment: I'd vote to close this a duplicate of some question explaining the difference between the different kinds of quotes, but a) I can't find one(?!), and b) there's already three close votes for other reasons than a dup so it wouldn't catch anyway.

Comment: @ilkkachu I couldn't find one either, so [I wrote one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/73093) - better answers welcome.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is not in `find`, but in how you're creating this directory. The single quoted string `'foo\n'` is actually a 5-character string, of which the last two are a backslash and a lowercase "n".

Double-quoting it doesn't help either, since double-quoted strings in shell use backslash as an escape character, but don't really interpret any of the C-style backslash sequences.

In a shell such as bash or zsh, etc. (but not dash from Debian/Ubuntu), you can use `$'...'`, which interprets those sequences:

```
$ mkdir $'foo\n'
```

(See bash's [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) for this feature, called "ANSI C Quoting").

Another option, that should work in any shell compatible with bourne shell is to insert an *actual* newline:

```
$ mkdir 'foo
'
```

That's an actual <kbd>Return</kbd> at the end of the first line, only closing the single quote on the second line.

Answer (score 6):

Let's make a directory named `foo` plus a newline:

```
$ mkdir $'foo\n'
```

Now, let's use find:

```
$ find .  -print0 | od -c
0000000   .  \0   .   /   f   o   o  \n  \0
0000011
```

`\n` is not escaped.

The issue is that `mkdir 'foo\n'` is the name is interpreted as `foo` followed by `\` followed by `n`.  We can verify that with:

```
$ printf '%s' 'foo\n' | od -c
0000000   f   o   o   \   n
0000005
```

Comment: I appreciate showing the verification part!