# echo return an empty variable $

Tags: variable, php, echo

I have this command

```
echo "<?php $x=$_GET['x']; echo $x;?>" > x.php
```

the output file x.php is:

```
<?php =['x']; echo ;?>
```

Has that any relation to the $ variable? and how do I avoid ???, so that I get the right php code in the x file?

Comment: If you don't need a replacement for this command, what do you need?

Comment: I mean I don't need to use cat or something else I need to avoid the $ problem ?

Comment: If you're asking how to prevent the shell from interpreting `$x` then the answer is here: [What is the difference between “…”, '…', $'…', and $“…” quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-and-quotes)

Comment: What is the _expected_ output?

Comment: The first php code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-and-quotes)

Comment: If you tell us what output you are expecting, then it would be easier to answer. I knew that you think that you have told us. You have not. You only have some code, and the wrong output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
echo "<?php $x=$_GET['x']; echo $x;?>" > x.php
```

Since the string that you pass to `echo` is double quoted, the shell will try to expand any shell variables in it.  The string contains two such variables, `$x` (twice) and `$_GET`.  If these variables have no assigned value, they will be replace by empty strings.

Assuming that you want to print the string as it is to the file, do this instead:

```
echo '<?php $x=$_GET['"'"'x'"'"']; echo $x;?>' >x.php
```

Here, I've put the string in *single* quotes.  This prevents the shell from trying to expand the things that looks like shell variables in it.

Since a single quoted string can't include single quotes, these would have to be added in a special way.  I've opted for adding them as `"'"` (double quoted single quotes) through concatenation with the rest of the string.

Alternatively, escape every `$` in the string:

```
echo "<?php \$x=\$_GET['x']; echo \$x;?>" >x.php
```

A third way is to use a quoted here-document:

```
cat <<'PHP_END' >x.php
<?php $x=$_GET['x']; echo $x;?>
PHP_END
```

This way you don't have to modify the actual string to make the shell treat it correctly, and you also don't have to remember that some shells' implementation of `echo` may do additional things with C-style escape sequences etc. (if you want to insert these into your PHP code).