# How to append text stored in a shell variable in the beginning of the file by using sed?

Tags: bash, sed, variable

I found interesting discussion here and tried the solution given with `sed`

> How to insert a text at the beginning of a file?
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533736/13353532

It works with normal text, but not when the text is saved in a variable.

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat file.txt 
1
2
3
wolf@linux:~$
```

Add text (`<added text>`) to the beginning of the file

```
wolf@linux:~$ sed -i '1s/^/<added text>\n/' file.txt
wolf@linux:~$
```

It works!

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat file.txt 
<added text>
1
2
3
wolf@linux:~$
```

However, when I tried it with variable it doesn't work anymore.

```
wolf@linux:~$ var='Text 1'
wolf@linux:~$ echo $var
Text 1
wolf@linux:~$ 

wolf@linux:~$ cat file.txt 
1
2
3
wolf@linux:~$ sed -i '1s/^/"$var"\n/' file.txt
wolf@linux:~$ cat file.txt 
"$var"
1
2
3
wolf@linux:~$
```

Instead of `"$var"`, how do I call the actual value of `$var` in `sed` command? I use GNU `sed` 4.7:

```
sed (GNU sed) 4.7 Packaged by Debian
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you have - as is recommended - enclosed the `sed` instructions in single quotes `' ... '`. However, inside single quotes, [variable expansion such as `$var` is disabled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/377345), and the expression remains verbatim.

As a solution, you can enclose the instructions in double quotes:

```
sed -i "1s/^/$var\n/" file.txt
```

Note however that I would recommend using the "insert" command for this purpose:

```
sed -i "1i $var" file.txt
```

will insert the content of `$var` before line 1.

**Edit**

As correctly stated by @DigitalTrauma in a comment: if you want to guard "all but the variable" against (unwanted) expansion, you can use a concatenated string argument with mixed quoting, which however mainly makes sense in the `s` command example:

```
sed -i 's/^/'"$var"'\n/' file.txt
```