# Print variable value in echo statement

Tags: bash, shell-script

How to pass the variable value in echo statement?

```
testvar="actualvalue"
echo 'testing "${testvar}", "testing", "testing" ;'
```

Expected output:

```
testing "actualvalue", "testing", "testing" ;
```

But, I am getting the below output:

```
testing "${testvar}", "testing", "testing" ;
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The single quotes in the `echo` command remove the special meaning of $.  Replace the single quotes with double quotes, and put backslashes before the other double quotes: `echo "testing \"${testvar}\", \"testing\", \"testing\" ;"`.

Comment: ... see for example [What is the difference between “…”, '…', $'…', and $“…” quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503014/65304)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the single quotes:

```
$ testvar="actualvalue"
$ echo testing "${testvar}", "testing", "testing" ;
testing actualvalue, testing, testing
```

The single-quote inhibits variable expansion.

Without double-quotes gives you the same output:

```
$ echo testing ${testvar}, testing, testing ;
testing actualvalue, testing, testing
```

But if you really want double-quotes in the output, escape them:

```
$ echo "testing \"${testvar}\", \"testing\", \"testing\" ;"
testing "actualvalue", "testing", "testing" ;
```

Comment: `${testvar}` outside double quotes is invoking the split+glob operator, so it would only give the same output in the special cases where `${testvar}` contains no wildcard characters nor characters of `$IFS`. Also note that `echo` can generally not be used to output arbitrary data. [You'd use `printf` for that instead](/q/65803).