# Postgres from script shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, postgresql

Hi I'm trying to create a database with owner ! the owner by default is postgres and I want to change it when a user creates a database

```
read -p "Enter owner database name : " $owner
read -p "Enter database name : " $my_db
sudo -i -u postgres psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE $my_db OWNER $owner'
```

I tested this line but it create a database name 'owner '

can someone help me ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues in your code snippet:

1. `$owner` in

   ```bsh
   read -p "Enter owner database name : " $owner
   ```

   *expands* the `owner` variable; it should be

   ```bsh
   read -p "Enter owner database name : " owner
   ```

   without the `$`; same thing for `$my_db`;
2. The single quotes in

   ```bsh
   sudo -i -u postgres psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE $my_db OWNER $owner'
   ```

   prevent the expansion of `$my_db` and `$owner`. It should be

   ```
   sudo -i -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE $my_db OWNER $owner"
   ```

   (note the double quotes in place of single quotes). A thorough explanation can be found in [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/315749)

Comment: yes this is soooo stupid i forget remarque 1

Comment: thanxx you very much