# print variable in a string of a string

Tags: bash

I don't know how to print a variable inside a string of a string.

I first started off without a variable like this and it worked perfectly:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh 1.1.1.1 $'sudo -H -u apache bash -c \'cd ~/html; echo development > stuff.text\''
```

When I login to my server at `1.1.1.1`, I can see that the file `stuff.text` has the word `development`.  Perfect.

Then I made this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=development
ssh 1.1.1.1 $'sudo -H -u apache bash -c \'cd ~/html; echo ${BRANCH} > stuff.text\''
```

But running this bash script causes an empty `stuff.text` file.  I also tried each of these commands, but they all gave syntax/parse errors:

```
ssh 1.1.1.1 $`sudo -H -u apache bash -c 'cd ~/html; echo ${BRANCH} > stuff.text'`
ssh 1.1.1.1 ${`sudo -H -u apache bash -c 'cd ~/html; echo ${BRANCH} > stuff.text'`}
ssh 1.1.1.1 ${sudo -H -u apache bash -c 'cd ~/html; echo ${BRANCH} > stuff.text'}
ssh 1.1.1.1 ${"sudo -H -u apache bash -c 'cd ~/html; echo ${BRANCH} > stuff.text'"}
```

How do I write a variable inside the string of another string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)

Comment: The notation you are using doesn't make sense. What exactly are you saying that your first command did? What do you think this is doing: `ssh 1.1.1.1 $'sudo -H -u apache bash -c \'cd ~/html; echo development > stuff.text\''`? You cannot escape single quotes, this is just a very complex notation to do something actually quite simple. Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @terdon, you can't escape single quotes within plain `'...'`, but you _can_ within a `$'...'`. Of course the syntax highlighting doesn't know it here.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks! I had never seen a shell context that allowed escaping single quotes like that before. Of course, the OP has no reason to use `$'...'` at all, but that's a different issue.

Comment: Instead of just throwing a bunch of syntax at the wall, I'd encourage you to read about bash quoting: [3.1.2 Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a needlessly complicated notation. The `$` isn't needed at all here, `ssh` takes a string that is executed as a command on the remote server. You also don't need to `cd` anywhere. Try this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

## avoid CAPS for shell variable names.
branch=development

ssh 1.1.1.1 "sudo -H -u apache bash -c 'echo $branch > ~/html/stuff.text'"
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of trial an error, I found that this worked:

```
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=development
ssh 1.1.1.1 $"sudo -H -u apache bash -c 'cd ~/html; echo ${BRANCH} > stuff.text'"
```

Now i can see the word `development` in the file `~/html/stuff.text`

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `ssh 1.1.1.1 "sudo -H -u apache bash -c 'cd ~/html; echo $BRANCH > stuff.text'"`, The `$` isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: `$"..."` is meant for locale translation of strings, you probably don't need it, just use regular `"...`"`. The problem in the code in your Q is that variables aren't expanded within `'...'` or `$'...'` See [What is the difference between the “…”, '…', $'…', and $“…” quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-quotes-in-th)