# Moving files from folder with carriage return in folder name

Tags: linux, mv

Provided my admin with a shell script to rename a few folders, but for some reason those folders now contain carriage returns in the name (the script worked fine in UAT, and I'm not quite sure what the difference is between the two environments.) My application creates a folder if it can't find it, so now I have two folders containing files that need to be merged.

So if I have folders: testfolder\r and testfolder, how would I *correctly* write the following command to move all files from the "CR" folder into the correct folder, preserving the contents of the correct folder in the event of any filename collisions?

```
mv testfolder\r/* testfolder/
```

Comment: Just a comment on _why_ this probably happened: File names are typically NULL-terminated strings, and can contain _anything_, including \\r (CR), \\n (LF), and even "/" or "\\", which are usually used as path name separators. _SOME_ API libraries will treat special characters like these as special, while others will not. You probably used an API library somewhere, or used Windows'-style line endings (CRLF instead of Un\*x LF), that interpreted the names differently.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash (or ksh or zsh) and GNU mv for its [`-n` or `--no-clobber` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mv-invocation.html#mv-invocation):

```
for file in testfolder$'\r'/*; do mv -n "$file" testfolder; done
```

This uses `$' ... '` [ANSI C quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503014/117549) to get the name of the folder with the carriage return in it; the rest is a simple loop to move -- and not clobber -- the files.