# How to give a parameter to a subshell written in quotes

Tags: bash

**How can I give a parameter to a subshell that has to be written in quotes?**

I have a bash function that does something with data, lets call it `check_data`:

```
check_data() {
    echo "I check data. \"$1\" looks good."
}
```

When I call it, I have to quote the parameter, if it contains spaces:

```
check_data "Adam Brutus Caesar"
```

But now I want to check the results of a `curl` request:

```
check_data $(curl --silent 'http://my.web.site.cool/myPath?arg1=Hey&arg2=Ho&arg3=$SESSIONID&arg4=Hi')
```

That of course only works if the result is a single word, otherwise only the first word would be checked. But when I quote the entire thing, ...

```
check_data "$(curl --silent 'http://my.web.site.cool/myPath?arg1=Hey&arg2=Ho&arg3=$SESSIONID&arg4=Hi')"
```

...`arg3` is not given the *content of* `$SESSIONID` but *the String* `$SESSIONID` instead.

What am I missing here?

Comment: you should already get that problem with `check_data $(curl ... 'http://...')` because the URL is in single quotes. The variable isn't expanded within single quotes

Comment: See: [What is the difference between the “…”, '…', $'…', and $“…” quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-quotes-in-th)

Comment: `check_data "$(curl ... "http://...$SESSIONID..." )"` with double quotes inside and out. And escape with backslashes if you need literal dollar signs in the URL.

Comment: Thank you very much @ilkkachu, double quotes inside and outside do the trick! I will read your link as well nonetheless. :-)