# Get updated output when using watch

Tags: watch

I use [watch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) to monitor the progress of file conversions.

```
watch -n 2 "echo Converted: $(ls *.mp3 | wc -l) of $(ls *.wav | wc -l) files"
```

When using command substitutions using the `$(command)` syntax the values don't get updated each time watch reruns the command within the double quotes. How to do this properly? Since this is a simple script with all kinds of "progress" monitors I'd like to keep the `watch` command and avoid something like [pv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv).

Comment: Related, if not even a duplicate: [What is the difference between the “…”, '…', $'…', and $“…” quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/170373)  (`$(...)` is called a command substitution, btw.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** you need to use singlequotes there, like this:

```
watch -n 2 'echo Converted: $(ls *.mp3 | wc -l) of $(ls *.wav | wc -l) files'
```

**Explanation**

Doublequotes are telling Bash to do string interpolation *before* passing the command to `watch`, so Bash evaluates those subshells, interpolates the output, and passes the whole shebang to `watch`, which never evaluates them again because it doesn't know about them.