# sed giving invalid arithmetic operator error

Tags: bash, sed, command, arithmetic

`sed` keeps giving invalid arithmetic operator error. I am trying to assign the output of sed to a variable.

This one works,

```
var=$(sed  -e 's/"currentGeneration":5010/"currentGeneration":5011/'  <<< $content )
```

but when I try to do the same with variable instead of 5010 and 5011, it fails with invalid arithmetic operator

```
var=$((sed  -e 's/"currentGeneration":$currg/"currentGeneration":$nextg/'  <<< $content ))
```

I tried below also but it won't substitute anything.

```
var=$(sed  -e 's/"currentGeneration":$currg/"currentGeneration":$nextg/'  <<< $content )
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something basic. Learning shell scripting on the job :(

Comment: Check your quoting

Comment: `$( ... )` is command substitution, `$(( ... ))` is arithmetic expansion. (If you're running that on an interactive Bash, the error message should begin with `bash: ...`, implying it's from Bash and not sed.) I can't tell any reason why the parentheses would have been doubled there. The other issue is with double quotes `""` vs. single quotes `''`, see [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-quotes-in-th)

Comment: Copy/paste that and any other shell scripts you write into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues that tool can tell you about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you command

```bsh
var=$(sed  -e 's/"currentGeneration":$currg/"currentGeneration":$nextg/'  <<< $content )
```

`$currg` and `$nextg` are not expanded [since they are not between double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes).

To avoid the problem, you have a couple of options:

- Use `sed` surrounded by double quotes and escape the inner double quotes:

  ```bsh
  $ var=$(sed  -e "s/\"currentGeneration\":$currg/\"currentGeneration\":$nextg/"  <<< "$content" )
  ```
- Concatenate single quotes with double quotes:

  ```bsh
  $ var=$(sed  -e 's/"currentGeneration":'"$currg"'/"currentGeneration":'"$nextg/"  <<< "$content" )
  ```

Note that `$content` should be enclosed in double quotes.

`((` [is a compound command to evaluate arithmetic operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html), so it's not doing what you intend to.

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me learn something as well.