# inotifywait : insert arbitrary string to output format

Tags: inotify

I want to capture inotify CLOSE_WRITE events in a directory and write CSV info to a history file.

My attempt :

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=/home/stephen/temp
host=$(hostname)
inotifywait -e close_write -m --timefmt '%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M' --format '%T,$host,%e,%w,%f' $dir | while read event;
do
    echo $event
done
```

This produces

```
2022-06-14,16:58, `hostname`, CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE, /home/stephen/temp/, testfile.txt
```

I've tried `$host` and `$(hostname)` with the same effect. The event's format definition does not accept externally defined variables.

I could wrap it all up in a python script but I'd rather find a shell native solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert any string (even multi-line) stored in a variable or use command substitution as long as you keep in mind the rules that apply to expansion when quoting. Anything inside single quotes will be printed literally. Break single quotes and use double-quotes for variables or command substitution that you want expanded. See
[What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013)

e.g. in your particular case using a format like

```
--format '%T, $host: '"${host}"',%e,%w,%f'
```

or

```
--format '%T, $host: '"$(hostnamectl hostname)"',%e,%w,%f'
```

prints

```
2022-12-20,06:21, $host: tuxedo,CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE,./,test
```

so the first `$host` is printed literally while the part between double-quotes is expanded to the host name.