# Bash variable inside another another

Tags: shell-script, shell

I'm trying to evaluate `dateFrom` variable inside `dateCalc` variable
that evaluate PHP command.

```
dateFrom="2013-01-05"
dateCalc=$(php -r '$date = new DateTime($dateFrom);echo $date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString("-2 days"))->format("Y-m-d");')
```

In the actual script, the date will be dynamic var.

Is there a way I can evaluate the `dateFrom` inside the PHP command?
if it's not possible, is there a way I can achieve the same result of the PHP command in another way? other shell commands?

Comment: What's the point of mixing two languages when you can do it all in PHP?

Comment: I can't use PHP here, I didn't how to do it inside shell script

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's best to pass the variable through the environment or as a command line argument:

```
$ export myvar=foobar
$ php -r 'printf("envvar is \"%s\"\n", getenv("myvar"));'
envvar is "foobar"
```

or

```
$ myvar=foobar php -r 'printf("envvar is \"%s\"\n", getenv("myvar"));'
envvar is "foobar"
```

or

```
$ php -r 'printf("arg is \"%s\"\n", $argv[1]);' foobar
arg is "foobar"
```

While you *could* embed the variable data in the PHP script itself, it would be a bad idea as anything the value would be confused with PHP syntax, unless you too really good care to make sure the value was quoted properly.

---

That said, if all you want is to get the date two days before, just using GNU date would do:

```
$ date -d '2013-01-05 - 2 days' +%F
2013-01-03
```

Or `n` days before any arbitrary YYYY-MM-DD formatted date stored in a variable:

```
$ dateFrom=2013-01-05 n=7
$ date -d "$dateFrom - $n days" +%F
2012-12-29
```

Comment: Thank you, I still need to use var inside var, how can I do it?
`dateFrom="2013-01-05"
dateCalc=$(date -d '${dateFrom} - 2 days' +%F)

echo $dateCalc`

Comment: I need to calculate 7 days ago from a specific date and do it again on the result.

Comment: @user531769, see edit

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, your example is not good because in my case I need the variable to be inside a command expression - backtick or $()

Comment: @user531769, and?

Comment: @user531769, if the command there gives the output you want, then you can store it in a variable by wrapping that same command in `$(...)`, and assigning to a variable. `var=$(date -d "$dateFrom - $n days" +%F)`. Don't change the double quotes to single quotes, it'll prevent that variable from being expanded. See: [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-quotes-in-th)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas,@ilkkachu  you are so right, I did try it yesterday and it didn't work but maybe I was tired because now it's working. many thanks!