# Awk variable passing error

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, ksh

Below works fine:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54}' FS='\t' OFS='\t' file.csv > file.csv.updated
```

But when I pass the column list through a variable it starts giving syntax errors.

```
awk -v FinalColumnVal=$FinalColumnValue '{$FinalColumnVal}' FS='\t' OFS='\t' file.csv > file.csv.updated
```

For Ref: I confirmed by printing the `FinalColumnValue` variable and it has the correct data.
`FinalColumnValue` is: `print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54`

Error:

```
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:      ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:            ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                  ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                        ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                               ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                       ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                               ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                               ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                               ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                               ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                               ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                                               ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                                                               ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                                                                               ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                                                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                                                                                               ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                                                                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                                                                                                               ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                                                                                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^ syntax error
awk: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12,$56,$13,$53,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$54
awk:
```

Based on various comments, I got to this working solution.

```
awk -v cols="$FinalColumnValues" 'BEGIN {n=split(cols,colarr,",") } { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) { printf $colarr[i] "\t" } printf "\n" }' file.csv > file.csv.updated
```

Where FinalColumnValues=1,2,3,4,5

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: two issues, your variable `FinalColumnValue` contains a space character and you're not preventing word splitting, so your awk script is `$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$57,$9,$55,$10,$11,$12...`, which doesn't seem to be what you want to execute. second issue, in awk `$var` does not evaluate the contents `var` as code, but represents the `var`-th field, or `$0` if `var` is not a number.

Comment: Perfect. I correct above 2 things and it works.     awk -v FinalColumnVal="$FinalColumnValue" '{print $FinalColumnVal}' FS='\t' OFS='\t' file.csv > file.csv.updated

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) and [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-quotes-in-th).

Comment: Also, it helps to post the full script you run, _exactly_, so the readers don't need to guess parts, or stitch them together from the description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest (untested):

```bash
columns='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,57,9,55,10,11,12,56,13,53,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,54'

awk -v cols="$columns" '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = "\t"
        n = split(cols, col, /,/)
    }
    {
        printf "%s", $(col[1])
        for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) printf "%s%s", OFS, $(col[i])
        printf "\n"
    }
' file.csv > file.csv.updated
```

More tersely, the main awk action can be:

```c
{ for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) printf "%s%s", $(col[i]), (i == n) ? ORS : OFS }
```

and instead of manually writing out every col number, you could replace this:

```
columns='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,57,9,55,10,11,12,56,13,53,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,54'

awk -v cols="$columns" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(cols, col, /,/)
```

with this:

```
ranges='1-8,57,9,55,10-12,56,13,53,14-52,54'

awk -v rngs="$ranges" '
BEGIN {
    numRanges = split(rngs,ranges,/,/)
    for ( i=1; i<=numRanges; i++ ) {
        split(ranges[i],range,/-/)
        for ( j=range[1]; j<=range[2]; j++ ) {
            col[++n] = j
        }
    }
```