# bash not parsing multi-word string into cli command

Tags: bash, ubuntu, github

What specifically needs to change in the `-f body=$DESCRIPTION` flag of the `gh api` CLI command in the GitHub workflow below
in order for a multi-word string such as `"Lots of new stuff"` to successfully be passed into the description of the
resulting GitHub release?

The problem we are currently having is that the `"Lots of new stuff"` string results in an error stating that the `body` expects 1 argument but received 4.

When we pass a single-word string into the same workflow, it runs successfully without error.

When we change the `body` flag to read `-f body='$DESCRIPTION'`, the resulting description for the release is rendered as `$DESCRIPTION`.

**WORKFDLOW CODE:**

```
name: release-manually
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      version:
        description: 'Version'
        required: true
        type: string
      description:
        description: 'Description of release'
        required: true
        type: string
jobs:
  release-a-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - shell: bash
        name: Release
        env:
          DESCRIPTION: ${{ inputs.description }}
          VERSION: ${{ inputs.version }}
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GIT_PAT }}
        run: |
          vers="_linux_"$VERSION
          echo "About to print version"
          echo $vers
          nameOfRelease="release_name"$vers
          echo "About to print name of release"
          echo $nameOfRelease 
          echo "About to create release"
          gh api \
            --method POST \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            /repos/AccountName/RepoName/releases \
            -f tag_name=$vers \
            -f target_commitish='branch-name' \
            -f name=$nameOfRelease \
            -f body=$DESCRIPTION \
            -F draft=false \
            -F prerelease=false \
            -F generate_release_notes=false
```

Comment: Since double quotes seem to work on the `-H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json"` line, I would try them around the value you're asking about:  `-f body="$DESCRIPTION"`.  Shells will expand `"$DESCRIPTION"` (wrapped in double-quotes) where they won't expand `'$DESCRIPTION'` (wrapped in single-quotes)

Comment: @SottoVoce The double quotes worked.  I just needed another set of eyes to look at it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think this question would let me learn a new thing, I stand corrected.

Firstly, I think the question could be flagged a duplicate of the [explanation of quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-quotes-in-th) as @rugk said at this [supposedly duplicate stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

Now the fun part is I had no idea there is functionality such as `VAR=$'hello\nworld'` which is exact same as:

```
VAR='hello
world'
```

Use `-f body="$DESCRIPTION"` and you should be fine. Also skim those links above and maybe have a look at [parameter expansion](https://linuxhint.com/bash_parameter_expansion/) as well for a through understanding.