# How does $code="Input" work when writing scripts?

Tags: scripting

I am writing my own script to install my Arch Linux.
I will only have few options to change every time I reinstall the system or use my script in another device.
Is there a way I can write the variables at the top of my script?
I came across something similar to the below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
disk="nvme0n1"
locale="en_US.UTF-8"
```

and then somewhere in the script there will be:

```
gdisk /dev/$disk
echo 'LANG=$locale' >> /etc/locale.conf
```

I can then just modify my variables at the top of my script every time I want to change something.

I am a beginner in writing scripts.
I am happy if someone can explain another/better way of achieving the above.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have done? You want `echo 'LANG=$locale'` or, better, `printf '%s\n' "$locale"` instead of `echo 'LANG=$locale'` because variables are not expanded in single quotes, but apart from that, what is the problem you are facing? How does it "not work"?

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach.  You'll receive advice to write your scripts to take changeable parameters like these ones as command-line arguments.  This is also good advice, but just as a child learns to crawl, then walk, then run, handling these kinds of parameters is a progression of skill and experience.  Your idea is a good one for "walking".  In your `echo` line use double quotes around the string where you want the variable expanded:  `echo "LANG=$locale" >> /etc/locale.conf`

Comment: Essionally what I am getting when I look into my locale.conf file is:
LANG=$locale instead of LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Perhapse, I need to know what are the prerequistes for this to work. Especially when the variable is in the middle of a command like these 2 examples I gave.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us: i) a script that we can run on our machines to reproduce the error, make it as simple as possible while reproducing the error; ii) the output you get from that script and iii) the output you expect. Also, please note what both earlier comments said about single quotes: you need double quotes if you want a variable expanded. So `echo 'LANG=$locale' >> /etc/locale.conf` will fail but `echo "LANG=$locale" >> /etc/locale.conf` will work.

Comment: see [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/170373)

Comment: Other than the single quotes, the snippets in your post look fine to me. But you have `$code=Input` in the title, and that _won't_ work in the shell (it'll expand `$code` and run the result as an argument, e.g. with `code=foo`, `$code=Input` would try to run a command called `foo=Input`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Yes, indeed the issue was the double quotes. I tested the commands in my question and they worked. I will apply this to my script and test it.