# find command: single vs double quotes

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I'm using "find" to rename files.

This works: `find . -iname a* -exec bash -c 'x={};mv {} ${x/a/b}' \;`

but this doesn't:
`find . -iname a* -exec bash -c "x={};mv {} ${x/a/b}" \;`

Why?

Running on Bash.

Thanks

Comment: Side note: [never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).

Comment: If you use double quotes, the `${x/a/b}` gets expanded by the shell instead of getting passed to `find` and get expanded by the `exec` command.

Comment: Thanks, understood .

Answer (score 1):

First, see: [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/170373)

> This works: `find . -iname a* -exec bash -c 'x={};mv {} ${x/a/b}' \;`

If you don't have any filenames in the current directory that start with an `a`, and if any of the filenames in the tree don't have whitespace or  characters special to the shell, then yes, perhaps it'll work.

> but this doesn't: `find . -iname a* -exec bash -c "x={};mv {} ${x/a/b}" \;`

The `"x={};mv {} ${x/a/b}"` part is double-quoted, so the shell expands the `${...}` right there, before running the command. `find` will see just the resulting string, probably `x={};mv {}` , since `$x` isn't likely to be  set in the outer shell.

In the first one, the single quotes prevent expansions, so `find` sees `x={};mv {} ${x/a/b}`, substitutes the filename for `{}` and passes the result to the shell you asked it to run. It might just work.

---

However, there are a few problems with that. The first one being the unquoted `-iname a*`. That will expand the glob in the shell, before running `find`, so if your directory contains e.g. `abcd.txt` and `asdf.txt`, it'll be the same as running `find . -iname abcd.txt asdf.txt`. The first filename goes with `-iname`, and the second is an error.

Then, the substitution of `{}`. Consider a filename like `foo bar.txt`, found somewhere in the tree. `find` changes `x={};mv {} ${x/a/b}` to `x=foo bar.txt;mv foo bar.txt ${x/a/b}` and runs it in the shell. But that's not the syntax you wanted, that'll assign `foo` to `x`, and run `bar.txt` as a command. Mixing code and data like this can hardly ever work, especially with filenames that can contain *any characters*. This also opens an obvious command injection vulnerability, e.g. with a filename like `foo; echo doing bad things`.

---

The proper way to do that would be to pass the filenames as positional parameters to the inner shell, and to quote the expansions in the script.

So,

```
find . -iname "a*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/a/b}"' sh {} \;
```

See:

- [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008/170373)
- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705/170373)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)