# Bash variable substitution into yq command

Tags: bash, command-substitution, variable-substitution, yaml

Given a YAML file, `example.yaml`:

```
node:
  sub_node:
    get_this:
```

I'd like to get a variable containing `get_this` using Mike Farah's `yq` and the string `sub_node`

```
yaml="$(cat example.yaml)"
nodename=sub_node
sub_yaml= "$(echo "$yaml" | yq -r '.$nodename' )";
# also tried -> sub_yaml= "$(echo "$yaml" | yq -r '.'"$nodename" )";
```

Note this is a contrived example, in reality, the `sub_node` string is not known in advance so I need to substitute the `$nodename` string.

I can't seem to figure out how to escape out of the single quote query string required by `yq`.

How might I do this?

Comment: [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-quotes-in-th). Double-quotes expand shell variables, single quotes don't. So `'.$nodename'` will pass the string `.$nodename`, while `".$nodename"`, will pass the string `.sub_node` as the argument to `yq`.

Comment: At least with [kislyuk's yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), you can pass variables in the same way you would to jq natively i.e. using `--arg` or `--argjson` / `$ARGS.named`

Comment: Do we need a `yq` tag at U&L? Better use the `YAML` tag.

Comment: @Philippos I was unsure whether to add it. Have done as suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Mike Farah's `yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/), you can get the value of the `nodename` shell variable into your `yq` expression as part of a path by accessing it from the utility's environment using the `env()` function, like so:

```bash
$ nodename='sub_node' yq '.node[env(nodename)]' example.yaml
get_this:
```

This accesses the subsection of the top-level `node` key given by the value of the `nodename` environment variable.

This *avoids* injecting the value of a shell variable into the `yq` expression, which means that you can access sections with dots and other special characters in their names.

---

Using [Andrey Kislyuk's `yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), a similar thing may be done by either passing the sub-key via an internal variable, like so:

```bash
$ nodename=sub_node
$ yq -y --arg sect "$nodename" '.node[$sect]' example.yaml
get_this: null
```

... or by reading the value from the environment,

```bash
$ nodename=sub_node yq -y '.node[$ENV.nodename]' example.yaml
get_this: null
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in ikkachu's comment, I should be using double quotes.

Ironically, it turns out that none of my trial and error efforts were working anyway due to the space I had after `=`.

I also had to correct the lookup string for the above example:

```
nodename=node.sub_node
sub_yaml="$(echo "$yaml" | yq -r ".$nodename" )";
echo $sub_yaml
get_this:
```