# Problem using dirname in a subshell

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget, dirname

I am writing a (one-line) script which should recurse thru subdirectories. Find .txt files containing hyperlinks. Use wget to get the contents and download it in the same directory where the text file is located.

Assume all text files found only contain valid hyperlinks.

To test this:
Create a subdirectory `./s1`
Create a text file `./s1/s1.txt`
Contents of `./s1/s1.txt`:  [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

This is the one-liner:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec bash -cx "wget -i \"{}\" -P  $(dirname \"{}\") " \;
```

The problem is that `$(dirname \"{}\")` does not expand correctly. The bash command being excuted is:

```
+ wget -i ./s1/s1.txt -P .
```

So `$(dirname \"{}\")` returns `.`
The effect is that a new **directory** `./s1/s1.txt` is created. So the downloaded file is stored as `./s1/s1.txt/index.html`

When I replace `$(dirname \"{}\")` with `$(echo \"{}\")` the output becomes:

```
+ wget -i ./s1/s1.txt -P ./s1/s1.txt
```

So parameter passing as such is correct. So I assume the result `dirname` is not properly returned to the calling bash shell. Or `dirname` is not evaluated at all.

When I execute only the bash command

```
bash -cx "wget -i ./s1/s1.txt -P  $(dirname ./s1/s1.txt)"
```

(so outside the `find` command) the command is executed as expected:

```
+ wget -i ./s1/s1.txt -P ./s1
```

What is the correct way to make this one-liner work?

Comment: The double-quoted `$(dirname \"{}\")` is being expanded by the interactive shell, rather than passed to the `find` command. In general, don't try to embed the find placeholder `{}` in shell code - pass it as a positional parameter instead. See for example [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely)

Comment: You have `$(dirname \"{}\")` within double quotes, so the shell expands it immediately, running `dirname` with the single argument `"{}"` (literal quotes included). There's no directory given in that path, so it returns `.`.

Comment: If you want the shell started by `find` to expand the command substitution, you have to prevent the outer shell from doing it before running `find`. See [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-quotes-in-th)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you could just do:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -execdir wget -i {} -P . ';'
```

Using the non-standard though very common¹ `-execdir` predicate of `find` instead of `-exec` to run the command from within the directory of the found file (and with `{}` expanding to the file name's instead of full path, possibly prepended with `./` with some `find` implementations including GNU `find`).

With GNU `find` and `xargs`, you can run a few in parallel with:

```
xargs -r0 -n4 -P10 -a <(
  find . -name '*.txt' -type f -printf '-i\0%p\0-P\0%h\0'
  ) wget
```

Where we get `find` to construct the  list of arguments for `wget` and output them NUL-delimited (0 being the only byte value that can't occur in an external command line argument of file path), `xargs` taking `4` at a time, to run `wget` instances, up to `10` in `P`arallel.

In `zsh`:

```
for file (**/*.txt(N.)) wget -i $file -P $file:h
```

(add the `D` *glob qualifier* if you also want to process hidden files like in the `find` approach).

---

In your

> ```
> find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec bash -cx "wget -i \"{}\" -P  $(dirname \"{}\") " \;
> ```

The `$(...)` is within double quotes, so is expanded to the output of `dirname \"{}\"` by the shell you're entering that command in before passing the result to `find`.

`dirname \"{}\"`, in sh/bash same as `dirname '"{}"'` like `dirname anything-that-does-not-contain-a-slash-and-does-not-start-with-dash` outputs `.` (a path to the current working directory).

So find is called with these arguments:

0. `find`
1. `.`
2. `-type`
3. `f`
4. `-name`
5. `*.txt`
6. `-exec`
7. `bash`
8. `-cx`
9. `wget -i "{}" -P .`
10. `;`

And `find` would run `bash` with these arguments:

0. `bash`
1. `-cx`
2. `wget -i "./path/to/the/file.txt" -P .`

For  each found file, and bash would in turn run `wget` with:

0. `wget`
1. `-i`
2. `./path/to/the/file.txt`
3. `-P`
4. `.`

But only if the *path to the file* doesn't contain `\`, `"`, `` ` `` nor `"` characters with potential disastrous consequences if they did (like if there was a file called `$(rm -rf ~).txt`).

While using single quotes instead of double quotes:

> ```
> find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec bash -cx 'wget -i "{}" -P  "$(dirname "{}")"' \;
> ```

would have fixed it, it  would still have been very wrong for the reason mentioned  above. `{}` should **never** be embedded in an argument that is evaluated as code. See [@Gilles' answer](/a/743053) for how to do it properly.

---

<sup>¹ `-execdir` AFAIK is from OpenBSD added there in 1996, in FreeBSD in 1997, NetBSD in 2002, GNU `find` in 2005, sfind in 2010, toybox in 2014 at least.</sup>

Comment: I marked this as the accepted solution because it is straightforward, elegant and completely does away with executing a bash shell which was a workaround in the first place.

Comment: In my version of wget it is not mentioned that -execdir is not standard. GNU Wget 1.21 built on linux-gnu. But maybe that is because it IS the GNU version.

Comment: @JohannesLinkels, ITYM *in my version of find*? See [there](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) for the standard specification of the `find` utility. IIRC `-execdir` is  from BSD, also added to  GNU `find` a long time ago.

Comment: You said it was non standard. Since I only use GNU I assumed you knew other versions.

Comment: @JohannesLinkels, `-execdir` is a non-standard `find` option, not `wget` option.

Comment: My bad to say it is a wget option. It it described in the find man page. But why non-standard?

Comment: @JohannesLinkels it's non-standard because it's not defined in the POSIX spec for the find command, which means that it's not guaranteed to be in every version of find.   In practice, though, unless you're using an ancient or proprietary version of unix with their own version of find, it'll probably have -execdir.

Comment: BTW, the fact that an option is non-standard also means that different implementations of that option may behave differently, because there's no defined way that it MUST behave - this is more likely to be a problem with other non-standard options in other programs than in find & -execdir.  e.g. POSIX `stat` doesn't have a standard printf option defined, but both GNU and *BSD have implemented different, incompatible options to provide printf output formatting. Compare https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?stat with https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, don't try to use `find` placeholder `{}` in the bash part. This is not reliable and have possible [security issue (shell injection)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/12574).

**Better use this way:**

```
 find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '
     for file; do
         wget -i "$file" -P "$(dirname "$file")"
     done
 ' sh {} +
```

or using a standard *parameter expansion* (which besides being more efficient has the advantage of still working if the directory name ends in newline characters):

```
 find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '
     for file; do
         wget -i "$file" -P "${file%/*}"
     done
 ' sh {} +
```

```
$ tree
.
└── s1
    ├── index.html
    └── s1.txt

1 directory, 2 files
```

Comment: Thanks you all. I accepted the solution by Stéphane Chazelas for the reasons mentioned in the comment of that asnwer. I am however guilty of setting up an XY problem. I posted a bash expansion problem, but actually it is a wget problem. I should not have used bash in the first place.

Comment: @JohannesLinkels, it's not a wget problem at all.