# Do I have to write a shell script purely to access bash for loops inside of say watch?

Tags: bash, for, watch

I'd like to monitor apps that have inotify instance in real-time with watch using something similar to:

```
watch "for foo in /proc/*/fd/*; do readlink -f $foo; done | grep inotify | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr"
```

I was hoping the output would appear similar to

```
for foo in /proc/*/fd/*; do readlink -f $foo; done | grep inotify | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

but instead this fails with a message about readlink having a missing an operand. I've been using using quotes to wrap my complex shell commands to view in watch for a while now and I guess I was surprised this one didn't work. I guess watch is designed for something different, just running a command and updating the output it sees. But I can't seem to bring this command up in sh or bash with:

```
watch "/bin/bash for foo in /proc/*/fd/*; do readlink -f $foo; done | grep inotify | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr"
watch bash "for foo in /proc/*/fd/*; do readlink -f $foo; done | grep inotify | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr"
watch sh "for foo in /proc/*/fd/*\; do readlink -f $foo\; done | grep inotify | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr"
watch bash "for foo in /proc/*/fd/*\; do readlink -f $foo\; done | grep inotify | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr"
```

but this gives sh: 1: Syntax error: "do" unexpected, and/or various syntax errors. After trying this one last thing (escaping the `;` with `\;`) but I get `/bin/bash: for: No such file or directory.`
but am curious to know why this works and if I can avoid using a script file, eg:  `watch which-programs-created-inotify-instances.sh`

Comment: Use single quotes or `$foo` will be evaluated by your current shell and not the shell started by `watch`.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate - [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/100397)

Comment: Hello, yes, it is better to answer your own question, and mark it as solved. Thank you for your feedback !