# Echoing "!" inside a string does some weird things

Tags: bash, zsh, quoting, command-history, history-expansion

If I type in this:

```bash
echo "Hello, World!"
```

I don't know the name of it, but it prompts me for the next line. You know the `PS2` thing. Or if you type `echo \` and press `Enter`.

Why?

Well I know that `!` is a **Special Variable** that you can use to reference your history.

But as soon as I use this:

```bash
echo "Hello, World"!
```

I get my desired output. What is happening and why can't you use `!` inside `""`?

---

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `set +H` is your friend to turn off history expansion. Personally, I keep that in my `.bashrc` everywhere.

Comment: use single quotes (') instead of double quites (") : they will prevent bash to attempt history expansion on the (!)

Comment: As @roaima already mentioned, you're most probably using `zsh`, not `bash`. You can check your shell with `echo $0`

Comment: What shell are you actually using? If you're not sure, you can use `echo $0` to find out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/590899/how-do-i-check-which-shell-i-am-using, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-interactive-shell-that-im-in-command-line

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`!` is not a special _variable. (There's a variable called `!`, which you can access with `$!`, but it's unrelated.) It's a character with a special meaning, depending on where bash sees it and on what comes after.

The `!` character starts [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html). Bash performs history expansion very early when parsing a command line, when it's reading commands interactively (not when it's running a script, even a script sourced with `.` or `source` from an interactive command line). You can set the variable [`histchars`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-histchars) to select a different character instead of `!` (but most other ASCII characters would conflict with common usage).

The character `!` [starts a history substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html)

> except when followed by a space, tab, the end of the line, ‘=’ or ‘(’ (when the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin).

So things like `echo "Hello, world"!` or `if ! grep -q foo myfile; …` don't trigger any history expansion.

Also [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html) and [dollar-single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) protect from history expansion (i.e. the history expansion character does not have its special meaning when within `'…'`), and a backslash that's quoting a character protects that character from starting a history expansion, but [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html) do not, except ([since bash 4.4](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-4.4#n332)) when bash is invoked in POSIX compatibility mode. That is, by default,

```
echo "!foo"
```

makes `!foo` a history reference which is substituted inside the double quotes. You can't simply include an actual exclamation mark in a double-quoted string, because `echo "\!foo"` would include the backslash. You have to use something like `echo \!"foo"` or `echo '!foo'`. I don't know why bash does this: it's a design decision made in the 1980s. (Bash inherits history expansion from csh where it's even worse: even single quotes don't protect from history expansion.)

I can't reproduce this exact case though:

```
bash-5.0$ echo "Hello, World!"
Hello, World!
```

But it might depend on the version or configuration of bash. The double quotes themselves don't inhibit history expansion: it's the fact that `!"` doesn't fit any of the forms of [event designators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html).

```
bash-5.0$ echo "Hello!world"
bash: !world: event not found`
```

Comment: "When using the shell [...] the history expansion character is also treated as quoted if it immediately precedes the closing double quote in a double-quoted string." -- That's probably why it works for you, the OP seems to use another shell than bash.

Comment: Whoopsie my bad, yeah you are right I am using `zsh`, completely forgot. Really detailed explanation from you thanks, I learned some new stuff :) But still, I don't get it why `history expansion` is triggered by *"nothing"*. Your answer even said *"The end of the line does not trigger it"*, yet still it does. Am I understanding something wrong? ^^

Comment: @Pixelbog In `echo "Hello, world!"` the `!` character is not at the end of the line.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Oh it is not? What else is at the end of the line then? ^^

Comment: @Pixelbog The last character is a double quote.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' ahhhhhhh oh okay. Now it makes sense, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using `bash` as tagged, use single quotes instead of double

```
echo 'Hello, World!'
Hello, World!
```

I think it's more likely you're using `zsh`, though, and the same fix applies:

```
echo "Hello, World!"
dquote>

echo 'Hello, World!'
Hello, World!
```

See [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/100397) for more information on the different types of quotes and when (not) to use them.

Comment: Your're right, showing a secondary prompt after `echo "stuff!"` looks like a zsh thing. In zsh, another workaround is `echo "stuff\!"`.