# Creating a command (with single quotes) using a command line variable and then executing it

Tags: bash, shell-script

My apologies for not being clearer with my first request.

I've been struggling with trying to get what should be a pretty simple bash script command to process but I'm getting screwed up by the single quote character.  My intent is to create a shell script that would accept a variable (a subnet notation) from the command line and then execute a command that would run the firewall-cmd command with some specific syntax (including single quotes, which is screwing me up), and then reload the firewall rules.  I'm using printf that creates the correct script, but I can't figure out how to execute that text string/line without getting "" characters in the output, and trying to create a variable with the string I want also screws things up.

So, I'd love to be able to type in "./banish.sh 1.22.228.0/24", it would execute the printf-generated command, and then also reload the firewalld rules.

My current code:

```
#! /bin/bash

printf "firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=$1 drop'\n" 
firewall-cmd --reload
```

I realize the "printf" command is really just echoing that text to the screen and not executing it (like it does for the "firewall-cmd --reload" line, but if I try to assign the output of printf to a variable, that then starts putting all the back slashes in it.

Any thoughts?
TIA

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/237982

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? I just ran the following and it worked: `export TEST='1.22.228.0/24' && printf "firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=$TEST drop'\n" | tee /tmp/test.txt`

Comment: _Show what you're doing._ The commands you have there don't even try to run that first `firewall-cmd`, and there are no backslashes on sight here. Anyway, I don't see what the point of the `printf` is to begin with, i.e. why mess with strings and not just run the command with the variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for all the help.  Bottom line, I was:

1. way over-thinking this, and
2. thought I had to use a single quote in the executed string, but actually a double quote works.

I'm pretty sure the problem was with trying to correctly include the single quote in the command.  What I've ended up with, which works, is:

```
#! /bin/bash
 
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family=ipv4 source address=$1 drop" 
firewall-cmd --reload
```

So now when I run the script, everything works correctly.  Thanks for the support on what should have been a trivial thing to do.

Comment: Indeed. See [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/170373) and also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes You still didn't show where you got the backslashes from, but I'm going to assume it's something like the output of `set -x`, where the backslashes are added for display purposes to make the output unambigous and valid as input to the shell again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use array variables to construct big commands with spaces in your parameters.

It's pretty to read, accept dynamic construction, ready for spaces into parameters, and more safe than `eval` command.

It's also fun to print commands.

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# One array item ("...") per parameter
declare -a fw_cmd_1=(
    "firewall-cmd"
    "--permanent"
    "--add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=$1 drop'"
)
declare -a fw_cmd_2=(
    "firewall-cmd"
    "--reload"
)

printf "Command 1: %s\n" "${fw_cmd_1[*]}"
"${fw_cmd_1[@]}"

printf "Command 2: %s\n" "${fw_cmd_2[*]}"
"${fw_cmd_2[@]}"
```

Comment: They likely don't want hard quotes in the `--add-rich-rule=...` argument. Not that the question shows it, but usually one doesn't and their self-answer shows that too.

Answer (score -3):

You can use backslash `\` scape character to ignore the nested quotes:

```
command="firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule=\"rule family=ipv4 source address=$1 drop\"" 
printf "$command\n"
$command
```

This should work.

Comment: Don't use `eval` command

Comment: @ArnaudValmary Thanks for the correction

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: You should probably reconsider what `eval` actually does, and what it would mean here (had it not been removed). And what it would mean if `$1` contained quotes etc.